# Why was the first servant(five talents) given an additional talent in Matthew 25?

Tags: matthew, parables, olivet-discourse

In the parable of the talents(Matthew 25:14-30) when the master returns he somehow rewards one servant more than the other

The first two servants had achieved the same results/output(100 percent) relative to what they had been given.The first two servants are given similar recommendations for their sterling work.

Matthew 25:20-21 ESV

> 20 And he who had received the five talents came forward, bringing five talents more, saying, ‘Master, you delivered to me five talents; here, I have made five talents more.’ 21 His master said to him, ‘Well done, good and faithful servant.[e] You have been faithful over a little; I will set you over much. Enter into the joy of your master

Matthew 25:22-23 ESV

> 22 And he also who had the two talents came forward, saying, ‘Master, you delivered to me two talents; here, I have made two talents more.’ 23 His master said to him, ‘Well done, good and faithful servant. You have been faithful over a little; I will set you over much. Enter into the joy of your master.’

But it is only the first servant(five talents) who seemingly is given an additional talent

Matthew 25:28 ESV

> 28 ***So take the talent from him and give it to him who has the ten talents***

Why was the second servant(two talents) not also given another talent?

.

Comment: I think the subtext of your question is: would a just God not reward fairly? I think he will, most definitely (and often wonder how that’ll work out for me..). I think it’s noteworthy to remember 1) this is a parable, just a story - not a depiction of reality at every level; 2) it was common, culturally, to exaggerate things to make a point when telling a story or giving a lesson.

Answer (score 2):

The lesson for the Parable of the Talents is in Matthew 25:

> 29
> For to everyone who has will more be given, and he will have an abundance. But from the one who has not, even what he has will be taken away.

The Parable of the Ten Minas is in Luke 19:

> 13 Calling ten of his servants, he gave them ten minas, and said to them, ‘Engage in business until I come.’

In this case, everyone is given a mina. Then he returned:

> 16 The first came before him, saying, ‘Lord, your mina has made **ten** minas more.’

1st servant makes 10 times in profit.

> 18 And the second came, saying, ‘Lord, your mina has made **five** minas.’

2nd servant makes 5 times in profit.

> 20 Then another came, saying, ‘Lord, here is your mina, which I kept laid away in a handkerchief;

This servant makes 0 profit.

> 24 And he said to those who stood by, ‘Take the mina from him, and give it to the one who has the **ten** minas.’

Give the mina to the servant who has made the most profit.

> 25 And they said to him, ‘Lord, he has ten minas!’ 26‘I tell you that to everyone who has, more will be given, but from the one who has not, even what he has will be taken away.

The same lesson is articulated in these two parables.
In both cases, the loser's money is given to the one who has the most money.

Why was the second servant(two talents) not also given another talent?

Because he wasn't the one with the most talents.

Answer (score 2):

Why was the first servant(five talents) given an additional talent in Matthew 25?

**Why was the second servant(two talents) not also given another talent?**

It does not really matter, both slaves take delight in representing their master, Jehovah, and increasing his interests on earth. Both are rewarded with entry into  His  Heavenly Kingdom:

Matthew 25:21

> 21 His master said to him, ‘Well done, good and faithful slave. You
> were faithful with a few things, I will put you in charge of many
> things; enter the joy of your  master.’

Isaiah poetically describes the joy of the slaves ;

Isaiah 61:10 ASV

> 10 I will greatly rejoice in Jehovah, my soul shall be joyful in my
> God; for he hath clothed me with the garments of salvation, he hath
> covered me with the robe of righteousness, as a bridegroom [a]decketh
> himself with a garland, and as a bride adorneth herself with her
> jewels.

Answer (score 0):

The talents in the parable (Mt 25:14-29) represent God’s grace, of which each person is given a certain measure (Eph 4:7). The criterion for distribution, however, is not determined by need, but "ability" (Mt 25:15); though it is doubtful that this word corresponds to our common notions of ability. And even if this grace is unfruitful in a person, it would not be lost but given to another.

The economics of God’s grace is not based on a system of limited resources, but one of abundance. Perhaps it could have been given to either of the two faithful servants (Mt 25: 20- 23), but that the talent of the unfaithful servant was given to the one who has more serves to illustrate the overflowing abundance of God’s grace and generosity toward those who are faithful to what they have been given.

> For to everyone who has, more shall be given, and he will have an
> abundance –  Mt 25:29
>
> And God is able to make all grace overflow to you, so that, always
> having all sufficiency in everything, you may have an abundance for
> every good deed –  2 Cor 9: 8
>
> Now to Him who is able to do far more abundantly beyond all that we
> ask or think, according to the power that works within us –  Eph 3:20

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't speak for any sect.

The ditch that most people seem to fall into when they try to interpret this is that they think that the wise steward was given a bonus for his productivity. That's not the point at all. What he received was a bigger portfolio to manage. His reward was greater responsibility because the boss is a capitalist boss, and he wants to milk his steward for all he's worth. If he's like God, then he probably had the unproductive worker tortured and killed. That's the point.

So in whom would a capitalist boss want to most exploit? The one with the biggest sales for the quarter.

Comment: disclaimers are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

When Jesus gave a footnote of His parable, the footnote is the primary of concern, and the exploration of the story becomes secondary.

In this parable of the talents (Matthew 25:14-30), Jesus gave a footnote;

> **29 For whoever has will be given more, and they will have an abundance. Whoever does not have, even what they have will be taken from them.** (Matthew 25:29 NIV)

This footnote exists two times in Matthew, and two times in Luke. Another time in Matthew is Matthew 13:12. Jesus just finished His parable of the Sower, His disciples did not understand why Jesus used parable in teaching, Jesus told them;

> 11 He replied, “Because the knowledge of the secrets of the kingdom of heaven has been given to you, but not to **them**.
>
> 12 Whoever has will be given more, and they will have an abundance. Whoever does not have, even what they have will be taken from **them**.
>
> 13 This is why I speak to **them** in parables: “Though seeing, they do not see; though hearing, they do not hear or understand.

Who is 'them'? In Matthew 13:9, Jesus said *"Whoever has ears, let them hear"*. So 'them' were those has ears, but couldn't hear/understand the words of God.

Another two times in Luke are in Luke 8:18 and 19:26.

> 18 **Therefore consider carefully how you listen.** Whoever has will be given more; whoever does not have, even what they think they have will be taken from them.” (Luke 8:18 NIV)

Luke 19:26 is within the parable of the Ten Minas. The story development is somewhat similar to the parable of the talent. Again let's focus on this footnote.

We may notice that this footnote is missing an object. *"For whoever has (???) will be given more (of ???), and they will have an abundance (of ???). Whoever does not have (???), even what they have (???) will be taken from them.*

Viewing all four places of its existent, we may deduce that the missing object is our understanding of the words of God. Both the parable of the talents and the parable of Ten Minas emphasized faithfulness, and faith is an essential element capable to hear the words of God.

> 21 “His master replied, ‘Well done, good and **faithful** servant! You have been **faithful** with a few things; I will put you in charge of many things. Come and share your master’s happiness!’ (Matthew 25:21 NIV)

> 17 “‘Well done, my good servant!’ his master replied. ‘Because you have been **trustworthy** in a very small matter, take charge of ten cities.’ (Luke 19:17 NIV)

Now why is the most be given extra? It corresponds to 'be given more and receive an abundance'. The extra is given by God, not taking from the unfaithful servant for he had nothing worthy to take. Note how it says;

"Whoever does not have (ears), even what they have (other than ears) will be taken from them.

It means if they did not belong to God, they will meet their destruction and lose everything.